# Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

i m getting this error while getting album art for the album.please explain me how this cursor works and how do i fix this error.

```
public  void getAlbums() {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0";
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,null, selection,null, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
             name = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID)));
             artist = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM)));
             artist1 = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART)));
            songInfo s = new songInfo(name,artist, artist1);
            _songs.add(s);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
        recyclerView1.setAdapter(albumAdapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please verify your `columnIndex`. In your case its -1 when you get `cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID)`. Based on your index, you have to increment to point the correct position

Comment: i didnt get it,please can you elaborate

Answer (score 1):

> Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow

Is saying that for row 0 (the first row in the cursor), it cannot read index(offset) -1. Index 0 is the first coulmn, 2 the 2nd etc. So you are tring to access a non-existant/impossible column.

However, the getColumnIndex method will return -1 if the column name passed to the method cannot be found as a column name.

Therefore one of these does not resolve/equate to a column name.

```
android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID
android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM
android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART
```

You could determine which by commenting out each line in turn. Alternately you could add the following after the line `cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,null, selection,null, null);` :-

```
String[] columns = cursor.getColumnNames();
for (String s: columns) {
    Log.d("CURSORCOLUMNS","Found column = " + s);
}
Log.d("NAMECOLUMN","The name column is " + android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID);
Log.d("ARTISTCOLUMN","The artist column is " + android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM);
Log.d("ARTIST1COLUMN","The artist1 column is "+ android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);
```

This will display the columns in the cursor followed by the columns that you are expecting to be in the cursor. One of the latter 3 will not be in the Found column = ????????. That will be the cause of the **-1**.